# How to run script to copy logs from remote server to local

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Here I am trying to run script from Server X and copy the logs from remote server ( Server Y) to local server ( Server X) home dir.

This is what I have tried. This copies the logs to server Y home dir.

```
user@X:/home ssh SERVER_Y  "bash -s" < ./get_logs SystemOut*
```

Update: How do I reference the server X in get_logs while running on remote server ( without hardcoding server name in script)

Apologies for updating the question.

Comment: @user000001 Your comment is answering the question user has asked, i guess better post it as answer.

Comment: There are many servers so I will have write scp for all and this will also require server name in .get_log script which I hesitate.

Comment: @N.G.U. So why not pass the server name(s) as argument(s) to the script? Re the multiple servers AFAIK the above commands only work for two endpoints at a time. Don't know any way of avoiding going in pairs.

Comment: @ user000001 Yes, This makes sense, I got this URL helpful.http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87405/how-can-i-execute-local-script-on-remote-machine-and-include-arguments Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
scp /localdir/bla/myfile somehost:/home/karl
```

Answer (score 0):

For download the whole directory from server to your current local directory

```
scp -r user@198.58.x.x:/var/log/ .
```

Here -r is used for recursively copy entire directories.

For single file downlod :

```
scp user@198.58.x.x:/var/log/some.log .
```

To upload log to your remote server :

```
scp some.log user@198.58.x.x:/var/log
```

Note : make sure you have read-write access to remote directory or file